# Error making request with Error Code MovedPermanently and Http Status Code MovedPermanently. No further error information was returned by the service?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an aws sample using the aws toolkit lambda project template. And published the project to Aws.

```
public class Function
{
    IAmazonS3 S3Client { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor. This constructor is used by Lambda to construct the instance. When invoked in a Lambda environment
    /// the AWS credentials will come from the IAM role associated with the function and the AWS region will be set to the
    /// region the Lambda function is executed in.
    /// </summary>
    public Function()
    {
        S3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs an instance with a preconfigured S3 client. This can be used for testing the outside of the Lambda environment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s3Client"></param>
    public Function(IAmazonS3 s3Client)
    {
        this.S3Client = s3Client;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called for every Lambda invocation. This method takes in an S3 event object and can be used 
    /// to respond to S3 notifications.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="evnt"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
        if(s3Event == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);
            return response.Headers.ContentType;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I test the function using the following `S3 Put` sample.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
          "name": "sourcebucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the response got the following error?

```
{
  "errorType": "AggregateException",
  "errorMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (Error making request with Error Code MovedPermanently and Http Status Code MovedPermanently. No further error information was returned by the service.)",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ],
  "cause":   {
    "errorType": "AmazonS3Exception",
    "errorMessage": "Error making request with Error Code MovedPermanently and Http Status Code MovedPermanently. No further error information was returned by the service.",
    "stackTrace": [
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
      "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
      "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
      "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
      "at StratsLambda.Function.<FunctionHandler>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\work\\Perforce\\Abs\\Strats\\StratsLambda\\Function.cs:line 64"
    ],
    "cause":     {
      "errorType": "HttpErrorResponseException",
      "errorMessage": "Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.",
      "stackTrace": [
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.HandleRedirect(IExecutionContext executionContext)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.<InvokeAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()"
      ]
    }
  },
  "causes": [    {
      "errorType": "AmazonS3Exception",
      "errorMessage": "Error making request with Error Code MovedPermanently and Http Status Code MovedPermanently. No further error information was returned by the service.",
      "stackTrace": [
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
        "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
        "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
        "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
        "at StratsLambda.Function.<FunctionHandler>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\work\\Perforce\\Abs\\Strats\\StratsLambda\\Function.cs:line 64"
      ],
      "cause":       {
        "errorType": "HttpErrorResponseException",
        "errorMessage": "Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.",
        "stackTrace": [
          "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.HandleRedirect(IExecutionContext executionContext)",
          "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
          "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
          "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
          "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
          "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.<InvokeAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()",
          "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
          "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
          "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
          "at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()",
          "--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---",
          "at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()",
          "at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)",
          "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is old, but there are no answers so... That error comes from making a request to a bucket using the wrong region endpoint. I can see you setting:

`"awsRegion": "us-east-1"`

Check that the bucket is in that region, and if not provide the correct region through config or in the constructor of the AmazonS3Client. e.g.

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config {ServiceURL = bucket, RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2};
var client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(s3AccessKey, s3Secret), config);
```